# local variable 'message' referenced before assignment

Tags: html, python-3.x

having trouble rendering 'user_message' variable in my html page from my python editor, the error page states "local variable 'message' referenced before assignment". I've looked at previous questions / answers on here but can't figure this out. Below is my code. Grateful for some help. Thank you

```
if request.method == "POST":
        new_user = request.form["username"]
        registered_users = users()
        if new_user in registered_users:
            user_message = "Sorry, this username is taken, please choose another"
        else:
            if request.method == "POST":
                user_list = open("data/users.txt", "a")
                user_list.write(new_user + "\n")
                session['user'] = new_user
                flash("Thanks for registering {}!".format(request.form["username"]))
    return render_template("register.html", register_message = user_message)
```

Comment: `local variable 'message'` Is not in this specific scope. Please post the code where the `message` was defined and used.

Comment: It is here in my html 
<h2 class="font-weight-light mb-0 flash">
          {% if user_message %}
          {{ user_message }}
          {% endif %}

Comment: That is the not the place where the variable was used. I'd suggest you recheck your error and post the proper stack Trace and help will come quickly.

Comment: Sorry, the local variable is user_message, not message

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `user_message` variable in your `return` statement but only defined it in one case, i.e the `if` statement. So you must define it in `else` block too, Or you can define `user_message`  above the `if-else` block and override it in case user already existed. Look for the comment so as to where to fix.

```
if request.method == "POST":
        new_user = request.form["username"]
        registered_users = users()
        if new_user in registered_users:
            user_message = "Sorry, this username is taken, please choose another"
        else:
            if request.method == "POST":
                user_message = "This user name available !!!" # <--- You need to define it in the else branch too
                user_list = open("data/users.txt", "a")
                user_list.write(new_user + "\n")
                session['user'] = new_user
                flash("Thanks for registering {}!".format(request.form["username"]))
    return render_template("register.html", register_message = user_message)
```